# defining doctype html is causing div height to be 0 pixel

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage, in which doctype is defined like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and corresponding style sheet consist of a division id wrap with just following property

```
    #wrap
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}
```

this causes the wrap to shrink to 0px in height although width remains 100%. But when the doctype tag is removed its according to property specified in css i.e width:100% and height 100%.
Possible Causes and solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make the height equal to window height, check this:

```
#wrap
{
   width:100%;
   height:100vh;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4o3vxbgu/

If you're trying to match the parent's height, use `height:100%` to all parent elements (including `body` and `html`).

```
html,body,#wrap{
 height:100%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4o3vxbgu/1/